# Ionic 1 push notification, push.register never been fire up

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

I've been followed the instruction on: http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/

And I use the code below in my after login function:

```
$ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
  console.log(t);
  return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
}).then(function(t) {
  console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
});
```

but it the register function with console.log never been fire up after I login.

Any idea?

Also I'm not using ionic Auth, so i didn't save the device token into user obj, and I think the auth user is not mandatory for the ionicPush, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can totally use Ionic Push without Ionic Auth.

Are you trying to run this code in your browser or on a device? It will only work on a device.

I suggest you to catch errors on your `register()` call first:

```
$ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
    console.log(t);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Thus, you will see why it's not working.

Comment: Hi, I just figure out, that the reason why my push.register method never been fire up because of the error of "push plugin not found".

Still no idea why i got this error, I've already install the plugin for android.

I also try to out the push.register method in run or in my login controller, but the error result shows different, in run, it said: push plugin not found. But in my login controller, it said: another registration in progress.

Any idea? 

Thanks.

Comment: You must call your register inside `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () { });`. You won't have the error "push plugin not found" anymore. About the error in your controller, maybe see this issue : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud-issues/issues/89

Comment: I've try to put this code in the ready():

$ionicUser.load().then(function () {
          console.log($ionicUser.details);
          $ionicPush.register().then(function (t) {
            alert(t);
            return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
          }).then(function (t) {
            alert('Token saved:', t.token);
          }, function (error) {
            alert(error);
          });

        });

But I still get the push plugin not found error.